# PDKKit html rendering

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, pdfkit

I am using pdfkit to generate pdf from html in ruby. I am able to generate the pdf but the rendered text on pdf has some characters which are unevenly spaced , even though the html rendering is perfect.

[image: snap shot]

```
def self.generate_invoice
      content = File.read( "#{Rails.root}/engines/restaurant_service/app/views/restaurant_service/settlement_mailer/settlement_invoice.html.erb")
      template = ERB.new(content)  
      set_margin = 0.1.to_s
      kit = PDFKit.new(template.result(binding), :page_size => 'Letter',:margin_top => set_margin+'in', :margin_right => set_margin+'in', :margin_bottom => set_margin+'in', :margin_left => set_margin+'in')
      kit.to_file(file_path)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add following lines to your config/initializers/pdfkit.rb

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.default_options = {
    :page_size     => 'Letter',
    :margin_top    => '0.1in',
    :margin_right  => '0.1in',
    :margin_bottom => '0.1in',
    :margin_left   => '0.1in'
  }
end
```

And then restart your server.